# How to set a Key name for each item in an initialized array

Tags: reactjs, setstate

I'm trying to initialize array `accessRoleDisplay` to unknown number of values and give each item in the array a key 'name' so I could use react table and add the value to the `accessor`

so it can look something like this

> 0: {name:xyz} 1: {name:xyz} 2: {name:xyz} . . . etc

This is my approach `accessRoleDisplay:[{name:''}]`  but this just sets the first item to a name key and the remainder without. Any feedback is appreciated!

```
class MainCard extends Component {
    state = {
        accessRoleDisplay:[{name:''}],
    }

    handleChange = (tab) => {

        window.alert(`Tab changed to: ${tab}`);
    };

retrieveRoleAccess() {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.state.accessRoleData.length; i++) {
        for(let j=0; j<this.state.resourcesResponseData.length; j++) {
            if(this.state.accessRoleData[i].resource_id === this.state.resourcesResponseData[j].id)
            { 
                this.setState((prevState) => ({
                    accessRoleDisplay: [...prevState.accessRoleDisplay, this.state.resourcesResponseData[j].name]

                }));
               
            }
        }
    }
    console.log('this is role access display: ',this.state.accessRoleDisplay )
}
   
    async componentDidMount() {
     this.retrieveRoleAccess();
        ...
    }
    shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
        return nextState !== this.state;
    }


    render() {


if (this.props.cardHandle) {
            return null
        }
        else {
            if (this.props.sendOptionSelected === 'Role') {
                
                return (
                    <Card mr={'0px'}>
                        <Tabs defaultActiveTab="Members" onChange={this.handleChange} >
                            {/* Group of tabs */}
                            <Tabs.Tab label="Members">Members</Tabs.Tab>
                            <Tabs.Tab label="Access">Access</Tabs.Tab>

                            {/* Tab panels */}
                            <Tabs.Panel label="Members">
                                <Table
                                    data={Array.isArray(this.state.outputRoleMembers) ? this.state.outputRoleMembers : [this.state.outputRoleMembers]}
           

                     defaultPageSize={[this.state.outputRoleMembers].length}
                                columns={
                                    [

                                        {
                                            Header: 'Fisrt Name',
                                            accessor: 'first_name'
                                        },
                                        {
                                            Header: 'Last Name',
                                            accessor: 'last_name'
                                        }

                                    ]
                                }
                                sortable={false}
                                resizable={false}
                                showPagination={false}
                                onSortedChange={() => { }}
                            />
                        </Tabs.Panel>
                        <Tabs.Panel label="Access">
                            <Table
                                data={Array.isArray(this.state.accessRoleDisplay) ? this.state.accessRoleDisplay : [this.state.accessRoleDisplay]}
                               
                                defaultPageSize={this.state.accessRoleDisplay.length}

                                columns={
                                    [
                                        {
                                            Header: 'Resource Name',
                                            //accessor: Need a key value here
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                                sortable={false}
                                resizable={false}
                                showPagination={false}
                                onSortedChange={() => { }}
                            />
                        </Tabs.Panel>
                    </Tabs>
                </Card>
            )
        }
}}}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        roles: state.roles.item,
        users: state.users,
        permissions: state.permissions,
        resources: state.resources
    }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getComponentById, fetchComponent })(MainCard);
```

Comment: Although it is not a very good practice, since there are no other unique values in your array, you can use the indices of the array as your key. But note that it might give you some bugs at some time

Comment: @NikhilAdiga Thank you for your feedback, Im looking to attach each value to a key 'name' instead of using indices. Do you know of an approach to do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a javascript Array:

```
accessRoleDisplay: Array(size).fill( {name: 'xyz'} ),
```

This will initialize an array of length `size` with the object `{name: 'xyz'}` at every index

Comment: I dont want to give the array an exact size and neither do I want to give each item a value of 'xyz' . I want to be able to give this array any information (take a look at function `retrieveRoleAccess`) and for that information to be linked to a key value

Comment: Why not use a map?

Comment: I had to modify it a little to work. This is how I did it `accessRoleData:[...prevState.accessRoleData, this.state.permissionsResponseData[i]]` Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 1):

**according to documentation**

accessor: String | Function

Required This string/function is used to build the data model for your column. The data returned by an accessor should be primitive and sortable. If a string is passed, the column's value will be looked up on the original row via that key, eg. If your column's accessor is firstName then its value would be read from row['firstName']. You can also specify deeply nested values with accessors like info.hobbies or even address[0].street If a function is passed, the column's value will be looked up on the original row using this accessor function, eg. If your column's accessor is row => row.name, then its value would be determined by passing the row to this function and using the resulting value.

*Its accept both string or function but make sure you set the id, you can do any operation on the row like row.attrbuiteName === null ? "no thing" : row.attrbuiteName*

```
{
     id:'name',
     Header: "Resource Name",
     accessor: row => row.attrbuiteName
     }
```

Comment: thanks for your feedback, but Im having trouble setting the array to a key value 'name' any idea how i should do that

Answer (score 1):

**Iteration over given Array to make key value pair**

```
var countries = ['Canada','Us','France','Italy'];
let obj = [];
for (var index in countries) {
    // don't actually do this
    obj.push({
        name: `name ${index}`,
        val: countries[index]
    });
}
obj.map((item) => item.name+ ' : ' + item.val);
```

OutPut -
**Key:name  value:val**

0: "name 0 : Canada"

1: "name 1 : Us"

2: "name 2 : France"

3: "name 3 : Italy"